# Neo4j. How to store additional parameters to entity already saved?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I need to have different parameters for `Device\Software` from `Entity` to `Entity`.
`Device\Software` will be stored at DB, and once new `Entity` created - it will make a relationship with some `Device\Software` which already stored, but their parameters could vary for different `Entities`(either the amount of parameters or their values).

I tried to save additional Parameters directly in the edge of the graph (in `RelationshipEntity` between `Entity` and `Device\Software`), but seems like it could add complexity during implementing some network comparison algorithm.

Does anyone had similar scenario? What is the best practice\approach?

```
@NodeEntity
public class Entity {

    @GraphId
    protected Long id;
    protected String title;
    /**
     * More fields here 
     */

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(direction = Direction.BOTH, type = "has_devices")
    protected Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<>();

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(direction = Direction.BOTH, type = "has_software")
    protected Set<Software> software = new HashSet<>();
}


@NodeEntity
public class Device {

    @GraphId
    protected Long id;
    protected String identifier;
    /**
     * More fields here 
     */

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(direction = Direction.BOTH, type = "has_parameter")
    protected Collection<ParameterEntity> parameter = new HashSet<>();
}

@NodeEntity
public class Software {

    @GraphId
    protected Long id;
    protected String identifier;
    /**
     * More fields here 
     */

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(direction = Direction.BOTH, type = "has_parameter")
    protected Collection<ParameterEntity> parameter = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`ParameterEntity` is just Key-Value object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean with parameters. But saving them on the relationship should work. You can ignore the params in your algorithm if you don't need them.

It really depends if you parameter just quantify the relationship or if they are real entities in their own right.

Comment: Parameters it's just a Key-Value object which will store any information user need ( e.g. "dateConnected" : "26.08.2015")

Comment: That's why you can store them directly at the relationship as properties

Comment: Could you please advise some easy method how could I retrieve entity and data which stored in relationship to that entity?
I know only about @RelatedToVia annotation. But it will return me a set of relationships which I should map manually.

Comment: Better is a cypher query on your repository that retrieves the entity information and the information from the relationships too.